# What is the type parameter that the compiler infers when using the diamond?

Tags: java, generics

I want to know what will be the type parameter that the compiler infers when creating a List and its parameterized type is bounded with `extends` or `super` clauses.

`List<? extends Number> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<? super Integer> integersList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discussed in detail in [§18 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html).

In your case, `List<? extends Number>` will be replaced with `List<Number>` since `Number` is the upper bound, whereas `List<? super Number>` will be replaces with `List<Object>` since `Object` is the upper bound. You can verify this by a quick test, I coded one up over on [<kbd>Ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3MEx7J)

For a discussion why this is useful, you may take a look at the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 0):

It infers whatever the type on the left side is.

`List` is equivalent too `List<Object>` so it'll infer to `ArrayList<Object>`.

`Map<String, OutputStream> map = new HashMap<>();` would infer to `<String, OutputStream>`

EDIT: You updated your question, but it still holds true, the left side will equal the right side, since it has to in order to set them equal

Comment: But I have tried to write this: `List<? extends Number> numbersList = new ArrayList<? extends Number>();` and this gave me an error because parameterized types can't be instantiated

Comment: You cannot use wildcards when creating concrete implementations.

Comment: @OmarMohamedKhallaf Ah I see what you mean, wild cards are taken out. So <? extends Foo> goes to Foo, whereas <? super Foo> will be able to take any object at runtime